# How to implement bootstrap glyphicon on multiple row in table using Jquery in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to implement  `bootstrap glyphicon` on multiple row in table using JQuery.

what I want is that if 1st row is clicked then 1st `glyphicon` should change, if 2nd is clicked then 2nd one should change and 1st one should go in normal position and so on.

Parent View

```
 <div id="Partial">     
    Html.RenderPartial("_Partial", Model);           
 </div>
```

Partial View

```
<table class="table">
      @foreach (var item in Model)
      {
        <tr class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ABC_@(item.Id)">
            <td>
                <button class="lCls" type="button">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"> @Html.Raw(item.H)</span>
                 </button>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.Raw(item.E)
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td class="hiddenRow">
                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="ABC_@(item.Id)">
                     <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                     @Html.Raw(item.D)
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                     @Html.Raw(item.B)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                     </table>
                 </div> 
            </td>
        </tr>                     
      }
</table>
```

JQuery

```
 $('#Partial').on('click', '.lCls',function () {
    $(this).children('span').toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-down");          

  });
```

Comment: What is not working with your code? Do you encounter an error?

Comment: @J.Loscos, I did not encounter any error. I am looking for some help to achieve this. I have pasted my code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems correct, you're just missing the part about reverting to the default position.

```
 $('#Partial').on('click', '.lCls',function () {
      $('#Partial').find(".glyphicon-chevron-down").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-down");
      if (!$(this).children('span.glyphicon-chevron-down').length)
           $(this).children('span').toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-down");          

 });
```

Comment: Could be shortened to `$(".glyphicon-chevron-down").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-down")`

Comment: But there is small problem in this. If there are 2 rows and if click on 1st row then `glyphicon` changes to `down` and if i click on 2nd row then 1st row `glyphicon` changes to `right`. That is working as expected. but the problem is when i click on 1st row  first time then `glyphicon` changes to `down` and again click on same row then `glyphicon` does not change to `right`. Please suggest.

Comment: You are right, there's a small problem with my answer when the user click twice on the same row. I edited it to add a test before toggeling the glyphicons